# How do I stop and start a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just looking to be pointed in the right direction here. I'm a beginner with javascript so there's some sort of fundamental thing I'm not understanding. Google searches didn't seem to help since apparently this question is never really asked.

I have a game where there is a 60 second countdown once the Go button is pressed. Now when that 60 second countdown is running I want to run a function orientationStuff() that does all sorts of stuff on orientationchange. This is no problem...HOWEVER

I only want orientationStuff() to run during the 60 second countdown. So once it hits 0, there is no more orientationStuff() going on. BUT once you click Go again I want the countdown to start again (and consequently orientationStuff()

Comment: I cant uderstand what you are tying to do, can you show your code? _this question is never really asked_ trust me it is an asnwer there, just your quesion is not clear enough

Comment: what does the orientationStuff function do and were is the code in your question. If its doing stuff on the screen like animations you could just use empty() or remove() to clear the DOM  after 60 seconds using a timeout function

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this in Javascript:

```
var i = 0; //counts every frame at 60FPS
function countdown() {
    function frame() {
        i += 1; //up the frame by 1;
        /* do stuff; you can use variable switch-based logic to perform different functions*/
        if(i > 3599) { /* equivilant of 60 seconds, you can add your own condition in if you want*/
            i = 0;
            clearInterval(looper_interval); //stops
        }
    }
    var looper_interval = setInterval(frame, 16); //this code runs the function frame() every 16 milliseconds
}
```

Comment: Yes, `setInterval`. Might want to mention that before setting the interval the OP should setup their orientation event handlers to run the game code, then remove the event handlers, display a score screen, whatever in the same block as `clearInterval`.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is you use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) with a function you want to execute and 60000 milliseconds

```
setTimeout(function(){
   // do whatever you want to happen here
},60000)
```

In terms of starting this with jQuery, if you had a button with a class `go` you would use

```
$(document).on('click','.go',function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
       // Game over man! GAME OVER!!
    },60000)
});
```

I guess you probably want to stop the timer - say if the player wins the game. In that case you capture an "id" from the timer and you can use `clearTimeout` to stop it

```
var gameTimerId = null;
$(document).on('click','.go',function(){
    gameTimerId  = setTimeout(function(){
       // Hury, before someone calls clearTimeout
    },60000)
});

/// where the player wins
clearTimeout(gameTimerId);
```

`setTimeout` runs the function once. If you want to execute a function repeatedly there is a similar function `setInterval` which you can use too.

Comment: I am pretty sure setTimeout() does not repeatedly run code but rather waits the specified number of milliseconds and then runs the function one time.

Comment: @GwiddleWorker and thats exactly what the OP asked for. Clicking the go button starts the timer again. "BUT once you click Go again I want the countdown to start again"

Comment: Except `setTimeout()` is horribly imprecise, and I believe will only execute if the JS call stack is currently empty, which might never happen if there is enough game activity happening.

Comment: Well I guess he was a but unclear, he says he wants to do "orientation stuff" so I don't know if he wants this to be executed atomically in one frame or over a gradual period of time within the countdown.

Comment: @JasonE.Wall I suspect, for this guy and many others writing their first game the accuracy will be just fine (ie if their game last 60.7s). But of course you're right in many cases.

Comment: I want orientationStuff to run while the timer is still counting. To stop when it stops counting. And to start again once it counts again. Let me know how I can make this more clear.

Comment: maybe it would help to see it in the browser. http://brocatz.com/headsup see how when you click go and change the orientation to the left or right youll see things happen. I only want that stuff to occur during the countdown. Stop. And then start once I decide to play again. EDIT: of course you would have to look on a phone to see orientationchange events...

Comment: i think this is the right answer. Just empty() or remove() from the DOM after a 60 second timeout. No one knows what the orientationStuff funtion does anyway, apart from the OP

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setTimeout` for 60 seconds and toggle a boolean value that you watch when providing the `orientationStuff()`.

If the `setTimeout` is inside a function, you can simply reset the boolean and rerun the function on the button.

**UPDATE**:

```
var orientationAllowed = false;
function orient() {
  orientationAllowed = true;
  setTimeout(function(){
    orientationAllowed = false;
  },60000);
}
```